# Boostrap modal blacked out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a modal but unfortunately it doesn't show up
The result I get is my web screen looking like this 
[It looks like what would be the outside of the modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6Z0J.jpg)
The Login above the form of my site changes font whenever I remove this and the modal becomes normal html this is what I noticed from making changes

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Thanks in advance

```
     <style>
        @font-face {
          font-family: Open-sans;
          src: url(OpenSans-Light.ttf);
      }

      body {
        font-family: Open-Sans;
        background-image:url('images/ElaionGb.jpg');
        background-size:100%;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }

    .contactform {
        font-family: Open-Sans;
        margin-top:-350px;
        width:190px;       
    }

    .contactform input {
        color:white;
        background-color:transparent;
        width:190px;
        height:40px;
        margin-top:7px;
        margin-bottom:7px;
        border-radius: 11px;
        border: 2px solid blue;
    }

    .sign {
        color:white;
        background-color:transparent;
        width:70px;
        height:40px;
        border-radius: 11px;
        border: 2px solid blue;
    }

    .submit-btn input {
        color:white;
        width:60px;
        height:40px;
    }

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</a>
        <h3>Welcome to elaion e-shop.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Sign-in to download the excel order file.<br>
        Modify as you please.<br>
        Attach and send to us.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a class="close">Close</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I guess you have some styling overwriting the bootstrap css. I see on line 1 of your exmaple code, you are ending a style tag. What is inside this? Would be great if you provided the full page in the example.

Comment: Try to remove hide class from modal, then it will show and then make css changes.

Comment: Also, I see you are importing two jquery libraries of different versions. You only need one.

Comment: @SølveTornøe if I remove 1 and keep the other the same thing happens I think you are right about overwriting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to delete the class hide

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>hi</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</a>
                <h3>Welcome to elaion e-shop.</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Sign-in to download the excel order file.<br>
                    Modify as you please.<br>
                    Attach and send to us.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a data-dismiss="modal" class="close">Close</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#myModal').modal({
                    show: true
                })
            });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `hide` class on your modal. Your modal is hidden by default. the hide class will set `display: none!important`, wich will overwrite bootstraps normal way of setting the modal from `display: none;` to `display: block;`

Also, you were missing two wrapper divs:

```
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
```

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#myModal").modal('show');
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</a>
          <h3>Welcome to elaion e-shop.</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Sign-in to download the excel order file.<br> Modify as you please.<br> Attach and send to us.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a class="close">Close</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the class `hide` is set from the beginning. This is preventing the modal from showing.
Change

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">
```

to

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
```